# Audio output device not detected until replugged

Tags: macos, audio, mac-mini

For a few months I have been facing a problem with my audio jack (3.5mm jack) on my Mac Mini late 2014 version - every time I reboot my computer, log out and log back in or turn off one of my monitors, my audio output device stops being detected until I replug it. Is anyone else facing such an issue, and if so - what steps can I  take to fix it?

[image]

I am currently using Mac OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Does your audio output device use the standard 3.5mm analog signal, or do you use the optical connection? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @Ic I have updated the question - it uses a standard 3.5mm jack.

Comment: This might possibly be caused by the plug being detected as a fiberoptic cable rather than a standard 3.5mm. Have you tried cleaning out the port on your Mac? When this happens, could you post a screenshot of Audio MIDI Setup with the output device selected?